What exactly are single and double quotes in coding?
I'm currently learning C#. I understand the difference in how double and single quotes work, but I can't quite define what they are exactly.?
Are they operators, or just is part of the syntax for defining these types of data or make an statement like semicolons (;) ?

A language needs a way to define literals. In C# it uses double quotes for strings, and single quotes for characters. "or just is part of the syntax for defining these types of data" it seems you already got it. I'm not sure what specifically you're confused about.

They are not operators as they do not perform any operation but rather they call them syntactic markers and are treated as such by the C# compiler.
Single quotes are used to define a char character data type (e.g. 'a' to define the a character)
Double quotes are used to define a string and are way more common in C# (e.g. "Hello Duban!"). You probably would store a lot of const string in your code.

Side note, tags don't always mean what you think they do and it's usually helpful to read their descriptions. Specifically basic here.

Closed? What should be added to the question that would not be the answer or irrelevant? Seems perfectly valid to me. Weird flagging.

Thanks. I understand that it is part of the syntax, but I didn't know how to refer to it inside c# or another programming language's context. I think 'syntactic markers' is the term I was looking for. @gunr2171

The ' and " characters are not operators. In technical terms per the C# specification, they are part of the definition of a character literal and string literal respectively. A literal is a way to represent a specific value within source code - for example, 123 is an integer literal, and 456.78 is a real (number) literal.
Just like how the . in 456.78 is part of the literal, so too are the ' and " characters surrounding the character and string literals. They are necessary to help the compiler and other tools distinguish arbitrary sequences of letters/numbers/punctuation as literals, instead of being interpreted as source code.

You might want to clarify "a real (number) literal" to "a number (double) literal".

The section of the spec I linked to calls them real literals, so I'll keep that name here. I put "(number)" in quotes to indicate it is an abridgment of "real number literal".

They're part of the syntax. An operator is a special character(s) that the programming language uses to do operations, like in python
"+" is for addition/string concatenation
"-" is for subtraction...
Because quotes or double quotes are needed to define a variable, and not to edit it in any way, they're just part of the syntax.

"define a variable" remember that literals are always constants and are created at compile time. They themselves cannot be variables.

In C#, double and single quotes are part of the syntax used to define different types of data:

Single Quotes: Used to define a single character (char).

For example:
char letter = 'A';

Double Quotes: Used to define a string(string).

For example:
string name= "DubanRG";

OP says "I understand the difference in how double and single quotes work"
